# How to put markers, show the route from A to B on openstreetmap using osmdroid for Android?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am building an Android app which shows an openstreetmap using the **osmdroid** library.

I managed to show the map, set zoom levels and center a location on the map in the app, but I need to put markers on certain locations and highlight particular routes from point A to B like in Google Maps API.

I went through the **osmdroid** documentation but couldn't find how to do this. Is there any tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: here : https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: Thank you, I'm going through it!